# How can I fetch the bagsList?

Tags: pallet, polkadot, kusama, staking, bags-list

I need to find my account's rank in the semi sorted bagsList hence I look for an API to do fetch that. why is it SEMIsorted that then needs to a rebag call that cost a fee? why it is not sorted at first place or kind of get sorted in the start of each era, snapshot time or any other suitable time?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more research I found that BagsList is not sorted because it is a Map not an array!

If someone wants to find if its address is included in the current round/era of staking:

```
    const MY_ADDRESS = '....';
    const assignments: Map<string, bigint> = new Map();
    const currentEra = (await api.query.staking.currentEra()).unwrap();
    const stakers = await api.query.staking.erasStakers.entries(currentEra);
    
    stakers.map((x) => x[1].others).flat().forEach((x) => {
      const nominator = String(x.who);
      const amount = BigInt(x.value);

      if (assignments.get(nominator)) {
        assignments.set(nominator, amount + (assignments.get(nominator)!))
      } else {
        assignments.set(nominator, amount)
      }
    });

    console.log('Am I in? :', !!assignments.get(MY_ADDRESS))
```